# How can I view the Certificate of a code-signed ESRI AddIn (*.esriAddIn) without ESRIRegAddIn.exe?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, add-in

For users with ArcGIS 10 installed, it's easy to view the certificate for a signed AddIn since it is presented to you in the Confirm Add-In file installation window.

Is there a way to view this certificate information if you don't have ArcGIS 10 installed?

As an alternative, can the ESRIRegAddIn.exe be copied to a computer without ArcGIS 10 and successfully run in order to view the certificate information?

Comment: Did you try renaming the addin file's extension from .esriaddin to .zip, unzipping it then check to see if there's certificate info in the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't copy `ESRIRegAddIn.exe` and it's required `DADFLib.dll` to another computer and run from there. Or rather, you can, but all it will do is say *"addin successfully installed"* without an opportunity to inspect the certificate. Tested in a virtual machine running XP and Arcgis 9.3.

From the online help for [Digitally signed add-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000009w1000000) I see there is another utility called `ESRISignAddIn.exe` that can be used to view (and add/remove) existing certificates. It is installed as part of the dot net SDK and located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin` or `C:\Program Files(x86)\...` if 64bit ([ref1](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14174-ESRISignAddin-Utility), [ref2](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/20830-Add-In-code-signing-and-timestamps)). You might have success using that file on another computer. Don't overlook that you'd likely be transgressing your ESRI License agreement.

As Kirk said, the addin distribution file is a just zip file with another extension. Rename to open in Windows Explorer, or use the free and open source [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) which opens darn near anything without needing to rename, and have a look. None of the Addins I looked at are digitally signed so I couldn't test that route personally. (Which begs the question: what good is the ability to check certs if no one uses them?)

Comment: As Kirk mentioned, the certs are in the AddIn but it's non-issue because we didn't end up using them.